# 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

In an attempt to apply the feature_importance attribute for a random forest classification model.
I have imported the relevant libraries:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators = 10, criterion = 'entropy', random_state = 0)
Importances = rf.feature_importances_
```

But I get this error:

```
'Sequential' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'
```

What could be the explanation for this? Thanks

Comment: Have you trained your model using `fit` function? I can't see it in you code.

Comment: yes.. i have. thanks for your swift response. apparently i botched the practice of proper naming conventions in my code base. Ha. So far down in my code, i had redefined  the rf and assigned it a sequential() for another model - neural network model. hence the error -  'Sequential' object has no attribute 'feature_importances_'. Thanks again.